# How to create cron statement to run for multiple hours

Tags: cron, cron-task

I need a cron statement to run for few hours eg 1-8 then 10-15. 
In this case will the following statement work,

```
0 1-8,10-15 * * *
```

If not can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You cannot, you can use either multiple values OR a range

`0 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15 * * *`

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20161128152110/http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html):

> Time tags are separated by spaces. Do not use spaces within a tag,
>   this will confuse cron. All five tags must be present. They are a
>   logical AND of each other. There is another space between the last
>   time tag and the first command.
>
> A time tag can be a wildcard "*", which means "all". It can be one
>   value, several values, a range, or a fractional range.

Answer (score 29):

I find it more readable to have two crontab entries:

```
0 1-8 * * * ...
0 10-15 * * * ...
```

Comment: +1. much cleaner/concise. downside is that if something in the command changes, you now have multiple places to edit it

Comment: you could use a bash script to encapsulate the parameters, Then, on crontab just call a single bash script for both entries.