# Linux Cron tab Expression for a job run in different hours

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I need to have a single cron tab entry  configured for a scheduled job

The job runs at

0-4 hours and then 16-20 hours

I tried this

```
0 */0-4,9-23 * * * some_report.sh
*/15 0-4,9-23 * * * some_report.sh
```

I checked this @ site http://cronchecker.net

but its not the correct entry..

How can i configure the cron expression for this job.

Comment: Why can't you have two entries?

Comment: @Leon , Thats the last resort.. but cant we configure it with a single expression. I believe we should be able to

Comment: I can have it as below..but i dont feel thats the best way to do it..                                                                            * 1,2,3,4,16,17,18,19,20 * * * some_report.sh

Comment: Does the job run for 4 hours? trying to understand why you have 0-4

Comment: @Leon : Basically it needs to run every 15 mts (*/15) for the first 4 hours of the day and then later part of the day, but here for the question i updated it as 0th minute.

Comment: You may want to check [Crontab command definitions](http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html) which is shown in [How to create cron statement to run for multiple hours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10811241/1983854). Basially, you cannot and you need to use the `1,2...` expression.

Comment: have you tried this cron, other than on cronchecker? because this tester gives a completely different result http://cron.schlitt.info/

Comment: I don't understand what times you want your job to run, every 15 minutes in the time between 0-4 and 9-23?

Answer (score 1):

`0 0-4,16-20 * * * some_report.sh` does exactly what you're asking.

Also try [crontab.guru](http://crontab.guru) for similar crontab questions.