# cron expressions for 2 hours ranges like 12:00AM - 6AM and 8PM - 11:59PM every day

Tags: cron, quartz.net, quartz

Can I define a cron job to run in 2 time ranges during the day? For example Every day between 12:00AM and 6:00AM AND between 8:00PM and 11:59PM.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create cron statement to run for multiple hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811241/how-to-create-cron-statement-to-run-for-multiple-hours)

Comment: The easiest way is to define a job with two triggers, one will run at the first schedule and the second one at the second schedule.