# Hangfire Job should run every hour between 12PM to 9PM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, devops, hangfire

Need cron expression for Hangfire jobs runs at every 2 hour between 12pm to 9pm starting from 12.05,2.05,4.05PM

Comment: See `man crontab` or examples, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16352399/10622916. It would be easier for us if you showed your (possibly non-working) solution. You can [edit] your question to do this.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can set([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10811298/14770824)):

```
5 0,2,4,6,8 * * * <your_job>
```